# Why can't I get file dropping to work with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to figure out how to do file drag and drop. I have read a number of tutorials and examples and think I know how to do it, but I can't get the absolute basic part working.

Here's the code I have currently. If I drag a file onto the filedropper div, the browser just loads the file instead of giving me the drop alert. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#filedropper').on('drop', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('drop');
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div id='filedropper' style='height:100px;width:100px;background:yellow'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you're using IE, this likely won't work at all.  IE (other than maybe IE 10) doesn't support file drag and drop.

Second, you need to catch and prevent the dragOver function in your $(document).ready:

```
$('#filedropper').on('dragover', function(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); } // The if checks are excessive but safest
    if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
});
```

[This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) was my primary reference when I was learning how to do it.

That should get you going.

[Check it out on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ozataj/2/edit)

Comment: And if you subscribe to dragenter or dragleave, you'll need to do the same there as well.